# how to set up pipes between Cygwin and Windows

Tags: windows, pipe, cygwin

What is the best way to emulate "pipe()"-like behaviour between a Cygwin and "true" Windows application?

As background, I have a Linux program where a C program calls "pipe", then forks a Rust program. The C and Rust program communicate via the pipes.

In windows the C program must be built with cygwin. There is no Rust for cygwin, but the program builds fine as a true Windows program. The only problem then is the communication.

Comment: Can you post minimal code of the C and Rust programs, as well as how you're running them (on Linux)?

Comment: I will make some, but I'm not sure it will be enlightening. I use 'pipe' to make some unnamed pipes, 'fork' to fork off the Rust program, then in the Rust program I use std::os::unix::io::FromRawFd to turn the fd of the pipes into Rust objects. Technically the FromRawFd call won't workon Windows (obviously), I currently comment itout, and will replace it with some windows-based socket once I figure out what I should use instead.